# Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callabel module (calling runApplication) , React Native , react-native-touch-id

Tags: react-native

I am facing this issue after installing `react-native-touch-id` package and then pod installation.
on ios. If I revert back this package and pod, apps works properly.

I tried reinstalling packge, pod, cleaning build, also a lot of googeling, stackoveflow, chatgpt etc. but did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue
I tried the below steps

1. `sudo find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +`
2. then `yarn`
3. Xcode -> clean build folder
4. `react-native start`